# Need to put fstream input file into a format that I can loop and decifer

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, ifstream

I'm going to have a data file that will be made up in the following manner.
Line one will be number of lines in the file [N]
The next line and each successive line will have three values. 
If value three is `>0` then that line item is a triangle.
If value two and three are `<0` then that line item is a circle.
If only value three is `<0` then that line item is a rectangle.

I can write algorithms to manipulate these items once I have separated them into circles,
rectangles and triangles but the problem is I don't know how to do that.

here's the code I have written so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// MAIN
int main(void)
{
    int N=0;
    ifstream Hinfo;
    // ........................................................
    Hinfo.open("Holes");
    if (Hinfo.fail())
    { 
        cerr << "Error:  open input file error" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    } 
    else
        cout << "Success:  input files opened" << endl;
    // ........................................................
    Hinfo >> N;
    float A[N];
    float B[N];
    float C[N];
    float Rec[];
    float Cir[];
    float Tri[];
    // ........................................................
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        Hinfo >> A[i] >> B[i] >> C[i];
    Hinfo.close();
}
```

I don't really know what to do next or if what I've done so far is the correct path
to take.

next I was thinking this to find rectangles, triangles and circles.

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    if (C[i] < 0)
    {
        if (B[i] < 0)
            A[i] >> B[i] >> C[i] >> Circle[];
        else 
            A[i] >> B[i] >> C[i] >> Rectangle[];
    }
    else
        A[i] >> B[i] >> C[i] >> Triangle[];
}
```

Would I be able to do this? Please help, I'm having a hard time managing all these arrays. Is there a simpler way to separate all this data into triangle, circle and rectangle arrays? Keep in mind that I'm a beginner so complex or advanced syntax will confuse my
fragile n00b mind

Thanks, Luke.

Comment: Variable length arrays are not allowed in standard C++. Some compilers allow them as extensions. You'll best solve this if you learn to use vectors - [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_%28C%2B%2B%29g]

Comment: I don't know what a vector is. We haven't learned about them in class (yet) so we should be able to solve this problem with only the things we've "learned" so far, which are variable types, cmath, arrays, loops, fstream inputs and outputs. Problem is, my professor doesn't teach anything--it's all riddles and mind games. If you think I'm being a mary about it check out his ratemyprofessor scores: http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=1348653

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is to have your three arrays, and an extra type array that stores an integer that signifies the type.(Note, you should use an enum for the type, but constants will also work)

This way you do not need separate arrays for each of the three types of shapes.

```
float A[N];
float B[N];
float C[N];
int type[N];

const int Triangle = 0;
const int Circle = 1;
const int Rectangle = 2;
```

Then you can do your loop to find the types

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    if (C[i] < 0)
    {
        if (B[i] < 0)
            type[i] = Circle;
        else 
            type[i] = Rectangle;
    }
    else
        type[i] = Triangle;
}
```

Then you can loop through the arrays again:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
   if (type[i] == Triangle)
   {
        // I am a triangle;
   }

   else if ...   
}
```

Of course you do not even need the second looping, but if your teacher wants it, this would be one way to do it.

Comment: If I were to skip the second loop and instead write a loop to sum the number of type circle, how would I go about it?                              Would it be something like this:                                              float sumC = 0.0;                                                          for (int i=0; i<N; i++)                                                       { if (type[i] == Circle)                                                 {sumC = sumC + type[1];}                                                 cout << "the number of round holes is " << sumC << endl;

Comment: @user1064407 It would be `if(type[i] == Circle){ sumC ++}`. And, the sum should be an integer, not a float.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is write a struct to hold a single data entry, probably like this:

```
const int TRIANGLE = 1;
const int CIRCLE   = 2;
const int RECTANGLE = 3;
struct Entry
{
    float points[3];
    int type;
};
```

This way, each time you read a line of values you can put them in a new Entry and set the type accordingly. Then you only need one array or vector to hold the entries. Or you can create an array/vector for each entry type.

```
std::vector<Entry> Entries;
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    Entry e;
    Hinfo >> e.points[0] >> e.points[1] >> e.points[2];
    if( e.points[2] > 0 )
        e.type = TRIANGLE;
    else if( e.points[2]<0 && e.points[1]<0)
        e.type = CIRCLE;
    else if( e.points[2]<0 && e.points[1]>=0 && e.points[0]>=0)
        e.type = RECTANGLE;
    Entries.push_back(e);
}
```

Something along these lines should do it.